# Is there a java reflection API around the java.lang.reflect package?

Tags: java, reflection

A lot of Java projects use reflection.  I wonder if is there a reflection library which make the use of `java.lang.reflect` easier.

We could use it like:

```
 Reflected object = new Reflected( new Object() {
        String name="Oscar";
        String lastName="Reyes";
        String reverseName(){
            return new StringBuilder(name+lastName)
                .reverse()
                .toString();
        }
        int nameLength() {
            return (name+lastName).length();
        }
    });
    String name = object.getString("name");
    object.set("name", "Mr. Oscar");
    String reversed = ( String ) object.exec("reverseName");
    int count       = ( Integer ) object.exec("nameLength");
```

```
.... 
UnknownLibraryObject reflectionMadeEasy 
         = new UnknownLibraryObject( .... );// initialize with an object from somewhere 

String someString = ( String ) reflectionMadeEasy.get("stringPropertyFromTheReflectedObject");
int someInteger   = ( String ) reflectionMadeEady.execute("someMethodFromReflectedObject", 1,2,3 );// with args.
```

Do every project that use reflection start from the scratch or is there a library already for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: is it possible to create classes at runtime in Java? this is exactly what you suggest. it is not Javascript.

Comment: @Andrey: Actually, you *can* do that in java. Reflective libraries like Hibernate and Spring AOP (to name but 2) do this all the time.

Comment: *is it possible to create classes at runtime in Java?* Of course it is. In this sample it is **not** not at runtime though, but compile time. Specifically using anonymous inner classes.

Comment: In this example you already know what your Object looks like at compile time, so why not create the separate class anyway?

Comment: Looks like the anonymous inner class was creating confusion. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides a number of convenient utilities classes to make reflection a bit less cumbersome, such as [`MethodUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/MethodUtils.html), [`FieldUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/FieldUtils.html) and [`ConstructorUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/ConstructorUtils.html). These typically provide one-liners to abstract out the often bulky raw reflection code.

As @Lauri pointed out, [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) is also available, providing more high-level functions, such as copying properties between objects.

Comment: @Lauri: Yes, that's useful also, although some of the more useful utilities from BeanUtils were migrated into Lang.

Comment: mmhhhhhh I a bit abstract to be explain, but let's say that I just want to use reflection. Every time I need to use it I found my self with these `Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod` kind of patterns, and knowing a bunch of OS projects use them, I was wondering if is there a *de facto* library for this.

Comment: @skaffman: So, which one is better at the end? ACL vs BeanUtils?

Answer (score 2):

See also java.beans.Expression and java.beans.Statement.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang is as straight forward as it gets. There is also [`Whitebox`](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation) which is PowerMock's Reflection Helper - here is the Quick Summary  from the wiki.

> ### Quick summary
>
> 1. Use Whitebox.setInternalState(..) to
>      set a private member of an instance or
>      class.
> 2. Use
>      Whitebox.getInternalState(..) to get a
>      private member of an instance or
>      class.
> 3. Use Whitebox.invokeMethod(..)
>      to invoke a private method of an
>      instance or class.
> 4. Use
>      Whitebox.invokeConstructor(..) to
>      create an instance of a class with a
>      private constructor.

I like it better than ACL as you don't have to be explicit with the `static`ness of the Fields and Methods.

Answer (score 2):

Most convenient is [jOOR](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR), with it your code becomes:

`Reflect.on(anyObject).field("stringPropertyFromTheReflectedObject").get()
Reflect.on(anyObject).call("someMethodFromReflectedObject", 1,2,3).get()`

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework contains some helpers, not all that different from Commons Lang/BeanUtils ...

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

Both classes are marked as 'intended for internal use', but still worth a look.

You may even find that you're really looking for a framework such as Spring to manage your objects ... hth

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but if you find yourself using the standard Java reflection APIs a lot, maybe there is something not quite right about the way you design and implement Java programs.

Java is primarily designed as a staticly typed language, and works very well when used that way.  While dynamic typing and (particularly) reflection can get you out of difficult problems, it is generally a good idea to restrict their use because:

- they reduces performance,
- they makes your source code more complex and less readable, and
- they make your code more fragile.

Hiding the reflection behind a library layer or within a Sping-like framework addresses the readability issue but not the performance or fragility issues.  (There are other approaches that *do* address all of the issues ... but without more information about why you are doing so much reflective programming, it is not clear they are relevant.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I'm aware of the nature of  reflection and I agree with you in the penalty it brings. This wasn't in the spirit of  *is it good to use it or not* type of question. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For **Spring Framework** users. There are some utility classes to work with the reflection easier:

- org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
- org.springframework.util.ClassUtils
- org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils
- org.springframework.util.TypeUtils